# Unit testing an async function in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous, testing

I am trying to test an asynchronous function in my swift project and I am receiving this error -> Thread 1: "Task created in a session that has been invalidated" on the second to last line of my test `wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 20.0)`

I know the API works and returns the data because it works when running the project and in Postman.

This is the unit test

```
func testRswPrice(){
        //Given (Arrange)
        let fromLat = 26.336502
        let fromLon = -81.439354
        let toLat = 26.533842
        let toLon = -81.759150
        let vm = LocationSearchViewModel()
        
        //When (Act)
        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Compute Price")
        vm.computePrice(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon){ value in
            expectation.fulfill()
            XCTAssertEqual(value, 8000.0)
        }
        // Wait for the expectation to be fulfilled, or time out after a specified duration
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 20.0)
    }
```

And this is the function inside the vm

```
func computePrice(_ fromLat: Double, _ fromLon: Double,_ toLat: Double, _ toLon: Double, completion: @escaping (Double?) -> Void){
        let url = URL(string:"NotShowingMyUrlToStackOverflowButPretendItsHere")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        print("fromLat: \(fromLat)    fromLon: \(fromLon)   toLat: \(toLat)    toLon: \(toLon)")
        let body = [
            "from": [
                "latitude": fromLat,
                "longitude": fromLon
            ],
            "to": [
                "latitude": toLat,
                "longitude": toLon
            ]
        ]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil,
                  (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200
            else{
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            //Decode JSON response
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response1 = try decoder.decode(PriceResponse.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(response1.price)
                    self.screenDisabled = false
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showingInvalidAlert = true
                }
                print("THE ERROR IS \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: You should never make an actual request against an external api in a unit test, mock that part instead. Search online for "swift mock urlsession" to give you some idea on how to do this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Why is that the case? this is an endpoint to my personal server for the app and I don't need to worry about too many requests etc.

Comment: It’s still a good practice to keep your unit test isolated and simplified. Now you have a dependency on an external resource and you are actually testing many things in one test.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Even if it's not best practice I would still like to create these tests. It's important to me that this code and my server are working correctly.

Comment: Maybe the test isn't working well with `DispatchQueue.main.async`, perhaps try without it just to see if that is the issue and/or add print statements or debug to see what is going on. Note that you have a bug when catching a decoding error since you don't call the completion handler then. Maybe it's time to move over to async/await...